# JS: Javascript closure issue in prototype instance

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

As for a JS-newbie, I'm struggling with JS-closure. Googled enough, though can't understand why "this" is not available in "store" function. Any help will be appreciated:

```
;(function (win) {
var _af = function(storeObjectName, storeObjectValue) {
    var self;
    if (_af.prototype.instance) {
        self = _af.prototype.instance;
    } else {
        self = Object.create(_af.prototype);
        _af.prototype.instance = self;
        self._init();
    }
    if (arguments.length == 1) return self.fire(storeObjectName);
    if (arguments.length == 2) self.store(storeObjectName, storeObjectValue);
    return self;
};

_af.prototype = {
    afVariable: '_af',
    afObject: {},

    _init : function(){
        this.afObject = this.get(self.afVariable);
    },

    store : (storeObjectName, storeObjectValue)=>{
        // This throws the error, that this.get is not defined
        this.get('_af');
    },

    get : storageObject=>{
        if (!storageObject)
            this.afObject = '_af';
        else
            this.afObject = '_someother'
    }
}
win._af = _af;
}(window));
```

Comment: how do you create `_af`?

Comment: What is your test? Are you calling `new _af` and then running `.store()`? Or are you just trying `_af.store()`?

Comment: Related [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch)

Answer (score 2):

It's because you use a `lambda expression` (`(...) => ...`) instead of `function() { ...`.

In JS `this` depends a lot on the context. In your case, since the prototype is an object, whenever you want to use `this` to refer to that object, you must do it in a function defined in the object like:

```
store : function(storeObjectName, storeObjectValue) {
    // This throws the error, that this.get is not defined
    this.get('_af');
},
```

or (also correct):

```
store(storeObjectName, storeObjectValue) {
    // This throws the error, that this.get is not defined
    this.get('_af');
},
```

Note you are doing it correctly for `_init`, but not for `store` and  `get`

When you use the lambda syntax, `this` will refer to the current this, when a function is created, so it will be `window`.

Also avoid using `get` as a function / or any other name because it is used for defining getters.

Comment: that's correct, the only thing is that _When you use the lambda syntax, this will refer to the outer object (in this case function (win))_ - it will refer to the current `this`, when a function is created, so it will be `window`, not `function (win)`

Comment: FWIW, the official term is "arrow function". Also, `get` is not a keyword.

Comment: Thanks, changing the lambda expression to regular function worked.